# Angular track by causing wrong element to be targeted

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I ran into this issue yesterday and was wondering if anyone had experienced anything similar and/or had an explanation for why this is happening.

Essentially, I have an ngRepeat block where I had been using `track by $index` (this was necessary for other reasons outside the scope of this issue). Each item in the list fired a method on click that would apply a class to itself (some CSS for exit effect) and then update it's status to be removed from the list.

Adding the class involved using a selector to target the item by an id associated with the argument to the ngClick method - each item would pass its own id. The ngRepeat collection is generated by a method that filters out any collection members with a particular property, which would also be added in the ngClick method.

The issue is that the class is being applied to two elements - the ngClick'ed element as well as the next element in the collection. Only the ngClick'ed element has the property added and is thus removed from the ngRepeat.

Additionally, `console.log`ing the selection shows some interesting results. Notice the selector versus the 0th element in the result set:

[image]

This is a simplified example of the controller logic:

```
$scope.list = [
    { name : "Joe",   id : 1},
    { name : "Clark", id : 2},
    { name : "Matt",  id : 3},
    { name : "Jimmy", id : 4},
    { name : "Bob",   id : 5}
];

$scope.getItems = function() {
    return _.reject($scope.list, 'clicked');
};

$scope.selectItem = function(id) {
   angular.element('#item-' + id).addClass('selected');
   _.each($scope.list, function(item) { if(item.id === id) { item.clicked = true; } });
};
```

And this is the ngRepeat in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in getItems() track by $index">
    <h5 ng-bind="item.name" id="item-{{item.id}}" ng-click="selectItem(item.id)"></h5>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h8bLm8pL/3/

To resolve the issue, I tracked by the id property of each collection member instead of the Angular internal `$index`, like `item in getItems() track by item.id`. Still, I'm unclear how this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because you are creating the id of the element in the loop but before that when a click event is processed it is targeting the previous element. Try this simplified solution.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in getItems()">
    <h5 ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="item.clicked=true" ng-class="{selected: item.clicked}"></h5>
</div>
```

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/VD9lXBtr4TyeviWau8l7?p=preview